# Specify Variable Size

Tags: variable-definitions, .netlink, data-types

Is there an easy way to specify the variable size and still use them as variables more specifically for the .NETLink?

Something like the following I am thinking.

```
t = Int[2];
```

and then the variable could only be set to unsigned int values as an example.

Anoter example I want `i = unsignedChar[3]` to be exactly 0 to 255 when you assign values to it.  So `i = 156` would either throw an error or overflow.

Comment: Is this any help?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133666/how-can-i-work-with-rawarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how close this is to what you are after:

```
ClearAll[t];
Module[{out = True},
 t /: Set[t, n_Integer] /; out := Block[{out = False}, t = n];
 t /: Set[t, whatever : Except[_Integer]] := $Failed
]
```

You can use whatever patter you wish.

```
t = 2; t
```

> 2

```
t = "test"
```

> ```
> $Failed
> ```

There is of course a question about SetDelayed and other methods to set different types of values.

Comment: my question is not very clear but Micheal is close to what I am after.  Essentially.  I want `i = unsignedChar[3]` to be exactly 0 to 255 when you assign values to it.  So `i = 156` would either throw an error or overflow.

Comment: So how would I automate the following so if I do `t=unsignedChar[2];` it would expand `ClearAll[t];
Module[{out = True},
  t /: Set[t, n_Integer] /; out :=
    Block[{out = False},
     If[0 <= n && n <= 255, t = n, False
      ]
     ];
  ];t=2;`